# How should I use "== null" if "==" operator is overloaded to be compared with several class types

Tags: c#, .net

I have class "A" that overloads "==" operator to allow instances be compared with instances of the same class "A" and instances of class "B".

It works ok but when I try to use "== null" (compare "A" class instance to null) compiler throws error:

```
Ambiguous invocation:
  bool == (A, A)
  bool == (A, B)
```

Is it possible to refactor class somehow to make "== null" compilable or  ReferenceEquals is the only alternative (funny, but "Yoda condition" null == A-class-instance works ok)

Comment: The reason the 'Yoda' case works is simple: null (Object) does not have an overloaded '==' operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way is just to cast:

```
if (a == (A) null)
```

That's assuming you *want* to call the overloaded operator. If you want to compare for reference equality, you can use either of these:

```
if (a == (object) null)
if (ReferenceEquals(a, null))
```

Personally I'd go with the second - I find it's more explicit and thus clearer.

My guess as to why the reversed version works is that there's no overload of `==(B, A)`.

Personally I would avoid overloading == like this anyway - it's highly unusual for instances of different types to compare as equal, particularly using ==. It's even worse if the operator hasn't been overloaded symmetrically:

```
bool x = (a == b);
bool y = (b == a);
```

If `x` and `y` can have different values here, you're really asking for a world of pain and hard-to-spot bugs. Just don't do it...

Comment: Honestly, it is a kind of "Variant" class that can be compared to "strings", "numbers", "variants" e.t.c. I wonder what is the best way to compare with null in such a case.

Comment: Caution: This will result in a call to the overloaded operator.  When comparing with null, you probably want reference comparison instead.

Comment: @Kevin: That depends; if it's a call from outside the class, it should be fine to call the overloaded operator, which should handle null correctly. Within the overloaded operator itself, it should use the reference comparison. I've edited the answer to make this clearer though.

Comment: @Andrew: I would change the design, frankly. This isn't COM, and variant types feel unidiomatic in C# to be honest. Within the overloaded operator I would use ReferenceEquals, but I really *wouldn't* overload the operator for multiple types - especially if you can't do it symmetrically. I'd add extra methods to compare the value in specific ways.

Answer (score 1):

Cast `null` to certain type, for example `(A)null`. It will remove ambiguity. And `null == null` and `(a != null) && (b == null) -> (a != b)`, means that it is logically safe.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28vs.80%29.aspx

To compare x (of type A) with null, use:

```
if (((object) x) == null)
```

or, more simply,

```
if (null == x)
```

This line works because null here has type Object, and Object does not overload the '==' operator.

The official line is "Use ReferenceEquals or cast the type to Object, to avoid the loop."

In your case, you are not seeing the infinite loop that Microsoft are refering to.  This is due to the resolution ambiguity.  The ambiguity is actually a secondary issue.

Comment: Not really. That describes how to implement a nullity check within ==. It doesn't say anything about how to differentiate between two different overloads of == when you've written both yourself.

Comment: True, but Andrew is specifically asking about the '== null' case.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your yoda condition works is that in both of your operators, the Left-hand operator is of type 'A'.  Therefore it can determine, based on the type of the right-hand operator, which of the operators to call.

As other posters have suggested, you need to cast it:

```
if(a == (A)null)
```